# How to send messages posted in Teams channel to external system in real time?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I need to send the messages posted in teams channel to external service. We can use webhook, but problem is we need to @mention webhook to receive notification. Can we achieve this without mentioning bot or webhook in the message? Is there any other tricks or logic?

When user post the message in Teams channel, my external system should receive notification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, **it is not possible to receive notifications other than using @mention**. The @mention is designed to get someone's attention in a channel conversation or a chat. Just type @ before their name and then select them from the menu that appears. They receive a notification, which they can click to go directly into the point in the conversation where they were mentioned.

Comment: I think there seems to be some ways. [Mio](https://m.io/) has the functionalities to pass the message posted in teams channel to slack channels. In their demo video, they haven't use **@mention**  while posting messages in Teams channel.

Comment: Haven't looked into the Mio functionality, but confirming from the MS Teams end that as of now one has to make use of @mention to receive notifications

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not supported to receive notification without @mentioning. Outgoing webhooks are scoped to the team level and are visible to all members of the team. Just like a bot, users required to @mention the name of the outgoing webhook to invoke it in the channel.